# MySQL won't start after setting galera cluster

Tags: mysql, service, galera

I've setted up 3 galera nodes. 
Then I started first mysql with `service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster` and it's SUCCESS, but when I tried to star my db2 and db3 I get error 
`[root@db3 ~]# service mysql start
Starting MySQL................................... ERROR!`

Here is my config files for db2 and db3:
db2:

```
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://191.168.2.130,192.168.2.127,192.168.2.128"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.127'
wsrep_node_name='db2'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=cluster_user:securepass
```

db3:

```
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://191.168.2.130,192.168.2.127,192.168.2.128"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.128'
wsrep_node_name='db3'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=cluster_user:securepass
```

EDIT:
Even if I stop the mysql on db1, db2 and db3 won't start.
When I type `service mysql status` on db2 and db3 it returns me  
`ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists`
and after service mysql stop I get 
 `ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!`

Comment: Did you solve the problem?  If not, could you check the mysql log (usually at /var/log/mysqld.log) on db2 and db3 to find any relevant info about the error?  Make sure also that the firewall does not block the communication between the nodes. Also make sure Selinux is disabled on all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

try 2nd cluster with below command-

```
service mysql start --wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://191.168.2.130,192.168.2.127,192.168.2.128"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs node-start the service and check wsrep_ready=on & primary status.
mysql service start --wsrep-new-cluster
mysql -u root -ppassword
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_status';
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_ready';Second node- service mysql start
Third node- service mysql start

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to open the firewall to the service. Add mysql as an allowed service.

> firewall-cmd --add-service=mysql --permanent
>
> firewall-cmd --reload

Then try to start the mysql service.

If this doesn't work, try just rebooting the server. Good Luck!